# Selenium Python returns unusual data

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract href from the following a tag

```
<a href="https://www.olx.ph/item/pioneer-pointe-condominium-unit-for-rent-1-br-fully-furnished-22k-ID8k7OP.html?h=ba76d6b70e&amp;utm_source=Opt_Homepage_Var_1&amp;utm_medium=Ad_Clicks&amp;utm_campaign=Phase_2" itemprop="url" class="funnel" data-category-id="137" data-funnel-type="Select Ad" data-action-type="Select Ad" data-funnel-userid="0">
                        <span class="title" itemprop="name">Pioneer Pointe Condominium unit for rent - 1 BR Fully Furnished - 22K</span>
                    </a>
```

I am using the following code in Selenium with python:

```
links=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@itemprop="url"]')
for l in links:
print(l)
```

and my current unusual output is :

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b6a29a1af20221f48056d6a8f34bd63", element="0.8368598264582081-1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b6a29a1af20221f48056d6a8f34bd63", element="0.8368598264582081-2")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b6a29a1af20221f48056d6a8f34bd63", element="0.8368598264582081-3")>
```

note: this is just a part of a output (first three lines)

These should be href of the a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just l returns the object that the browser has found you must specify which part of the object you want

```
for l in links:
    print(l.get_attribute("href"))
```